# textarea is not showing correct value

Tags: angularjs

I have a textarea with ng-model="commentsText" value coming from model is 'my comments are here'. If commentsText doesn't have any value then only it should show default text as 'N.A' but it is always showing 'N.A' not a binded model value.

```
    <textarea name="myTextArea" class="form-control" rows="3"
    ng-init="commentsText='N.A'" ng-model="commentsText"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please share your component code and the html in your question. Thanks.

Comment: <textarea name="myTextArea" class="form-control" rows="3"              
     ng-init="commentsText='N.A'" ng-model="commentsText">N.A</textarea>

Comment: response from rest call is binded as
$scope.commentsText = $scope.comments;

Comment: rather than using ` ng-init ="commentsText='N.A" ` in your html . after  line `$scope.commentsText = $scope.comments;` in your controller check if `$scope.commentsText` has empty value if it is empty then assign "commentsText='N.A" into it

Comment: sorry I am getting $scope.commentsText is empty 4 spaces... thats why it is nor null nor empty... type is giving string with stringlength as 4. how to handle this?

Comment: $scope.comment.trim() did a job of removing extra spaces and gave me the wanted empty value. Thanks alot for help!!